# Jquery animate scrollTop не рабоатет

Tags: javascript, jquery

Любой другой код работает. Я удалил все скрипты полностью, оставил только этот - не работает. На других страницах (кстати, да на этой, тут есть комментарии), этот код работает.

```
$('.comments-here').on('click', function(){
    console.log('1')
    $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: $('.comments').offset().top - 90}, 800);
    console.log('1')
});
```

Все консоли выводятся. Не могу понять, что не так. Вне `on('click')` скролл тоже не работает

Comment: Ошибок нет никаких, просто ничего не происходит

Answer (score 0):

Проблема была в том, что на `body` был `display: flex; flex-direction: column` . А так же `html, body, main {height: 100%}` . Убрал высоту и все заработало.